# The purpose of Rosh Hashana

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rosh-hashanah-new-year, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

What should a person try to accomplish on Rosh hashana?

I know yom kipur is about teshuva. but what is the goal of Rosh hashana?

They say that it is the "Head" of the year, which means the root of the entire year, so it must be important; however, the goal is somewhat vague.

Answer (score 5):

Rosh Hashana 16a, 34b

> The Holy One Blessed is He said ... on Rosh Hashana recite before me verses that speak of Sovereignty, Remembrance and Shofar Blasts. Sovereignty so that you should make me your king. Remembrance so that your remembrance should rise up before me for your benefit. And through what? Through the Shofar.

Couldnt be more clear. Crown Hashem, Recite versers of Rememberance to gain favor!

Comment: so what does it mean "make me your King". this is the only thing one should focus on?

Comment: @RaymondSebag The Nefesh HaChaim 2 (11) says that the prayers of Rosh Hashono are concerned with the glory of the Kingship of HaShem and even the **daily liturgy**, he says, contains disguised pleas for the increased awareness of His glory by mankind. So that's the main thing. If the fulfillment of your personal requests will also increase His glory, then ask for them too. (Sorry no othersources - no time.)

Comment: Seconding yehuda's answer (and Avrohom Yitzchak's comment) but want to add the obvious suggestion that you can flesh out the ideas by reading through the holiday-specific content of the amidah for Rosh HaShanah. The quoted gemara is talking about musaf, but there's also the special content 'uvkhein tein pahdekha' in the 3rd blessing of all other amidot of the day. Mandating that that's what the content of the prayers should be seems to be a way of point you towards what it would be good to think about.

Comment: @Yehuda or to anybody, please provide a clickable link to: Rosh Hashana 16a, 34b